# Packstack installation error：Error appeared during Puppet run: 182.200.101.182_network.pp

Tags: networking, openstack

I'm trying to install openstack pike and get the following error:

```
Applying 182.200.101.182_network.pp
182.200.101.182_network.pp:                       [ ERROR ]
Applying Puppet manifests                         [ ERROR ]

ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 182.200.101.182_network.pp
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, no address for  at /var/tmp/packstack/97726d22166b49baa95345c407c57d9d/modules/packstack/manifests/neutron/ovs_agent.pp:50:27 on node client182
You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20210429-095103-0t__pO/manifests/182.200.101.182_network.pp.log
Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20210429-095103-0t__pO/openstack-setup.log for more information
Additional information:
 * Time synchronization installation was skipped. Please note that unsynchronized time on server instances might be problem for some OpenStack components.
 * File /root/keystonerc_admin has been created on OpenStack client host 182.200.101.182. To use the command line tools you need to source the file.
 * To access the OpenStack Dashboard browse to http://182.200.101.182/dashboard .
Please, find your login credentials stored in the keystonerc_admin in your home directory.

182.200.101.182_network.pp.log
^[[1;33mWarning: ModuleLoader: module 'neutron' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: ModuleLoader: module 'openstacklib' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: This method is deprecated, please use match expressions with Stdlib::Compat::Array instead. They are described at https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_type.html#match-expressions. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/97726d22166b49baa95345c407c57d9d/modules/neutron/manifests/init.pp", 524]:["/var/tmp/packstack/97726d22166b49baa95345c407c57d9d/manifests/182.200.101.182_network.pp", 18]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/97726d22166b49baa95345c407c57d9d/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_bond0';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_eno2';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_ens1f0';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_ens1f1';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_ens6f0';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_ens6f1';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;33mWarning: Undefined variable 'ipaddress_virbr0_nic';
   (file & line not available)^[[0m
^[[1;31mError: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, no address for  at /var/tmp/packstack/97726d22166b49baa95345c407c57d9d/modules/packstack/manifests/neutron/ovs_agent.pp:50:27 on node client182^[[0m
```

Appreciate if anyone help to fix this issue

Comment: You are installing Packstack. Why such an old release? I am not sure if Pike is still supported; it may have bugs that were fixed in later releases. Better follow [official instructions](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/). Did you disable NetworkManager and the firewall? Is this a fresh installation of Centos or RHEL? Did you search the internet for "Time synchronization installation was skipped" or the other error messages? Which command did you use to launch the installation, which answer file parameters did you set if any?

Comment: Because my work need to install this version.It is a fresh installation on rhel 7, and I have disabled NetworkManager and firewall.I use packstack --answer-file=packstack-answers，parameters are default,only change password

Comment: I have done many Packstack installations. Only once did I hit a [bug](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/103016/packstack-requirement-for-python-tinyrpc-breaks-installation/); all other cases of failure where due to my errors. Therefore, I still think you did something wrong. Perhaps a mishmash of different versions? How did you install the Packstack software in the first place, and on which version of Centos?